# How to generate large integer private key for creating CTF challenges?

Tags: rsa, attack

I am trying to create a RSA CTF challenge, exposing $n$, $e$, $c$, and $d$.

I have set $e=65537$ and $n = p * q$ where $p$ and $q$ are large primes each with 300 digits.

I have determined $c=m^e \mod n$

But I have yet to determine a good way to produce $d=e^{(-1)} \mod [(p-1)*(q-1)]$. I tried computing the right as is via code, but

```
from decimal import Decimal

print(Decimal(e**(-1)) % phi)
```

returns something like $0.00001525855623540900559906297040$, and I want a natural number. What is an efficient way to producing a large $d$? Is there tool/website/software/algorithm/calculator/etc. for creating a large $d$?

TLDR: Something like [this website](https://asecuritysite.com/encryption/rsa) but works with rather large numbers.

Comment: Btw., the python code calculates `e**(-1)` over the real numbers, so its the same as what you would get when using a calculator and typed in `1/e`. Since the result is between zero and `phi` the modulo operation `% phi` does nothing. What you actually need here is the multiplicative inverse modulo $\varphi(n)$, so you need to find a $d$ such that $e\cdot d\equiv 1\mod{\varphi(n)}$. (That is the meaning of $e^{(-1)}$ in $d=e^{(-1)}\mod{((p-1)\cdot (q-1))}$.)

Comment: Ah yes, I just thought that the `Decimal` would do some nice computation for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) to calculate $d$. Quoting Wikipedia, given $a$ and $b$, the extended Euclidean algorithm gives you $x$ and $y$ such that

$$ ax+by = \gcd{(a,b)}.$$

Since $e$ is prime, $\gcd{(e, \varphi(n))}=1$, so the algorithm gives you $x$ and $y$ with

$$ex+\varphi(n)\cdot y=1$$

which means

$$ex \equiv 1 \mod{\varphi(n)}$$

and thus you can use $x$ as $d$.

---

For your practical application, the truly marvelous Python standard library has a [trinary pow function](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#pow) build in that can calculate the modular multiplicative inverse beginning with Python 3.8

```
>>> p=17125458317614137930196041979257577826408832324037508573393292981642667139747621778802438775238728592968344613589379932348475613503476932163166973813218698343816463289144185362912602522540494983090531497232965829536524507269848825658311420299335922295709743267508322525966773950394919257576842038771632742044142471053509850123605883815857162666917775193496157372656195558305727009891276006514000409365877218171388319923896309377791762590614311849642961380224851940460421710449368927252974870395873936387909672274883295377481008150475878590270591798350563488168080923804611822387520198054002990623911454389104774092183
>>> pow(3,-1,p)
5708486105871379310065347326419192608802944108012502857797764327214222379915873926267479591746242864322781537863126644116158537834492310721055657937739566114605487763048061787637534174180164994363510499077655276512174835756616275219437140099778640765236581089169440841988924650131639752525614012923877580681380823684503283374535294605285720888972591731165385790885398519435242336630425335504666803121959072723796106641298769792597254196871437283214320460074950646820140570149789642417658290131957978795969890758294431792493669383491959530090197266116854496056026974601537274129173399351334330207970484796368258030728
>>>
```

Comment: I did some investigating after posting. That algorithm is tangent to the algorithm that will find $d$/$x$ for me: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse Thank you tho!